# Layout for longer chapter title in Memoir class

Tags: sectioning, indentation, memoir, chapters

I am using `\chapterstyle{section}` with `\Huge\sffamily` font. This means that some longer chapter titles spread over two lines. I get (a larger version of!)

> 2 A long title splitting as illustrated here
>   over two lines

with the second line starting at the left margin, when I'd *like* the second line to be indented to start under the first word of the title.

This must be easy to effect (without cheating and putting in an `\hspace!`), but I'm not seeing how from the `memoir` manual.

Comment: The MemoirChapStyles example for memoir shows how to set up very fancy chapter headings, with the relevant source code. Perhaps that suggests a solution to your problem. Some of the styles use largeish figures surrounding the chapter number, replacing that with a box might work. OTOH, I'd take seeing the overlong title as a strong nudge to shorten it...

Comment: A sample title that doesn't fit on one line is "Preliminaries about relations and functions" so not *very* long! Thanks for the pointer to the MemoirChapStyles.pdf document. But I can't (yet!) spot a solution to my simple(?) problem in the source codes for those much fancier layouts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not that simple. One might get by by using a hanging paragraph, here is another solution, which though has the disadvantage that one has to use `\newline` to force a line break

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{calc}
\makechapterstyle{section}{%
  \chapterstyle{default}
  \renewcommand{\printchaptername}{}
  \renewcommand{\chapternamenum}{}
  \renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}
  \renewcommand{\printchapternum}{}%\chapnumfont \thechapter\space}
  \renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{}
  \renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{} p{1cm} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\textwidth-1cm}}
      \chapnumfont\thechapter & \chaptitlefont ##1
    \end{tabular}
  }
}
\chapterstyle{section}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Some very long title that hopefully span two lines}
\end{document}
```

Edit: Looking though the `memoir` sources, it turns out this is very easy, have a look at the `reparticle` style, so this is enough

```
\makeatletter
\makechapterstyle{section}{%
  \chapterstyle{default}
  \renewcommand{\printchaptername}{}
  \renewcommand{\chapternamenum}{}
  \renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}
  \renewcommand{\printchapternum}{}%\chapnumfont \thechapter\space}
  \renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
       \@hangfrom{\chapnumfont \thechapter\quad}}%
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Tried the simpler version: it works a treat. Many thanks!